# How can I check all checkboxes except the disabled ones?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

If I click on `checkAll` I want to check all checkboxes except the disabled ones.

```js
$("#checkAll").click(function () {
  $(".projectlist input:checkbox").each(function () { 
    if($(this).is(':enabled')){
     $('.projectlist input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="projectlist">
<input id="checkAll" type="checkbox"><br>
<input disabled type="checkbox"><br>
<input disabled type="checkbox"><br>
<input type="checkbox"><br>
<input type="checkbox"><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$("#checkAll").click(function() {

  $('.projectlist input:checkbox:enabled').prop('checked', this.checked);


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="projectlist">
  <input id="checkAll" type="checkbox"><br>
  <input disabled type="checkbox"><br>
  <input disabled type="checkbox"><br>
  <input type="checkbox"><br>
  <input type="checkbox"><br>
</div>
```

1. use [:enabled()](https://api.jquery.com/enabled-selector/) selector

> Description: Selects all elements that are enabled.

Comment: Wow! So simple! I was thinking so complicated... Thank you

Comment: @Jarla glad to help mate happy coding :)

Comment: Yes happy :) :)